# Try to split packet using PcapDotNet

Tags: c#, pcap.net

In my application, I want to add the option to split my packets and I have found this post:

[Split packet into 2 packets with pcapdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272565/split-packet-into-2-packets-with-pcapdotnet)

i split 1 TCP packet into 2 packets and the 2 packets received is **TCP** and **Ipv4**, is it normal or i should received 2 **TCP** packets ?

Comment: Are you fragmenting an IP packet so you send out 2 IP fragments  ? If so what do you mean that you receive 2 packets TCP and IPv4 ? Which application is receiving it , which is sending something ? Anyway, it doesn't make sense to look at the TCP layer until you have reassembled the fragments of an IP packet is fragmented

Comment: i can't get what you are trying to do ?

Comment: hey, Its not good to do that. IP fragmentation: The Internet Protocol (IP) implements datagram fragmentation, so that packets may be formed that can pass through a link with a smaller maximum transmission unit (MTU) than the original datagram size

Comment: i have special server that "catch" those 2 packets and know to merge them.

Comment: Can you give the code you use and link to a .pcap file output?

Answer (score 0):

Please see discussion and solutions in http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/350211